# Why can't I comment in the review queue?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, comments, reviewing

I recall being able to comment in the review queue before. I liked this since it let me leave helpful, personalised comments to guide newer users in the right direction.

However, it seems like it's recently been removed. This seems especially odd, since the guidelines say that you can complete a review by commenting...

[image]

This happens in Low Quality Posts too (and presumably others, but the others are all empty for me right now), even though that queue explicitly states "You can also leave a **comment** on the answer".

Why has commenting been disabled in review queues? And, if there is a good reason for this, can we at least remove the conflicting information?

Comment: Probably related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198951/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-first-posts-reviews

Comment: This is currently a bug, as noted by Billy. We're working on fixing it.

Comment: This should be fixed as of last night.  Could you verify for me before I answer?

Comment: @BenCollins Yep, it's been fixed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments have been getting some refactor-love, but not without a few issues.  This should be fixed now.